# In Jquery context menu how can i identify the right clicked element is href or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    <div id="divis" contenteditable="true" style="width:250px; height:200px;border:1px solid">
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a></div>
    <div id="custom-menu">  
    <ol>
    <li><a id ="a1" href="#">Removelink</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Reply All</a> </li>
    </ol></div>


$('#divis').bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$("#custom-menu").css({ top: e.pageY + "px", left: e.pageX + "px" }).show(100);
$('#a1').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
    document.execCommand('unlink',false,null);
});
});
```

here it is shwoing the li a href attribute ie."#
" i want to know that when i right click inside the content editable div(divis)  there i want to know that i right clicked on what element is it a href or any other html element ot tag. then i want to do the unlink option function, but i am stuck here please help me

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: How i know that i right clicked on this <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a></div> href??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[is](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** method

```
$(e.target).is('a#a1')
```

Comment: you beat me by 15 seconds :D

Answer (score 0):

```
('#id').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            alert('Left mouse button pressed');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('Middle mouse button pressed');
            break;
        case 3:
            if($(e.target).is('a#a1'))
               .................

            break;
        default:
            alert('You have a strange mouse');
    }
});
```